# How to load complex array of triangles into CGAL's Nef Polyhedra to do 3D Boolean Operations on it?

Tags: c++, geometry, cgal

So I have an array of vertexes + triangles (not one solid enclosed body; multiple triangles some unified some, not alike N islands/planes). I want to treat all these vertexes + triangles as one Nef Polyhedra and perform boolean operations on them. How to load all that unconnected triangles into Nef Polyhedra? (my kernel is `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel`)

Comment: does it define a close solid or not necessarily?

Comment: @sloriot: Not necessarily. (mostly not)

Comment: The function OFF_to_nef_3 is doing what you want if the triangle are stored in a file using the OFF format. I guess you can try to do the same in memory.